# Why is Captain America unbeatable?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger

I know how Captain America became the First Avenger from **Captain America: The First Avenger (2011)** and it is done in **1942, America has entered World War II.**

My question is, **why is he in perfect physical and mental condition?**

How long does he have that strength through his lifetime? Why didn't he get any side effects from the laboratory experiment?

Comment: looks like you have 3 questions here, 1) why is he unbeatable 2) why no side effects and 3) why doesn't his power decay over time. Please can you clarify which is the actual question and consider breaking the other 2 out into their own questions

Comment: yes In my mind all 3 questions rounding ... I need clarification even I get down votes ......

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR I didn't downvote, but the possible reason is that you're asking multiple questions in one post.

Comment: and plz comment for down votes .... I will rectify next time.... tq

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR sorry if you misunderstood me, on SE you should ask 1 question at a time. You have asked 4. Try to make this about just 1 of those questions, and if you need to know the answer to the other 3 ask them as 3 separate questions

Comment: yes but when we are fulfilling one answer we need to satisfy all the possible scenarios.... I think all these questions will come in one question only .

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR I have edited your posts as an attempt to make it less-broad and to avoid future downvotes. Please follow this thing next time. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you ... @AJ and  @ Cearon O'Flynn next time I will consider all these points .

Comment: Captain America is unbeatable because he has both Hulk and Wolverine on speed-dial.

Comment: It's not safe to assume that he didn't get any side effects from the laboratory experiment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Steve Rogers/Captain America is in perfect physical condition as a result of the super serum he was injected with.  This took him from a small, weedy person unfit for military service into who he is today.

His mental strength is a combination of the serum and his own beliefs and convictions.  Leading up to the super serum experiment, he is shown as standing up for what he believes is right, regardless of whether standing up for them means he gets beaten up.  Those ideals are what got him chosen above all others when it came to the experiment. The serum amplifies those aspects, just as they enhanced Red Skull into the strong but ultimately bad person he was.

From those two paragraphs, we can deduce that he has had his physical strength since the serum injections, and his mental strength from before then.  His mental strength is part of who he always was.  However, he has always had a large amount of physical endurance, which is partially (at least) down to his mental toughness.  In the first avenger when he's being beaten up for standing up to someone talking in the cinema, he's repeatedly punched to the ground but gets up saying:

> I can do this all day

He can tough it out because his mental strength allows him to keep going.  The serum enhances that.  This mental strength gives him the belief he can do a lot with the body he's been given, and therefore allows him to push on through different injuries, like when The Winter Soldier shoots him on the helicarrier.

Arguably he has had side effects from the experiment.  His enhancement is a side effect of it, and his increased mental toughness is also one.  Whilst that was the intended outcome, he also has to live with knowing he's likely to outlive his friends due to an enhanced healing factor and the fact he was a "Capsicle" for years after *The First Avenger* took place.

Due to the relatively short time which has passed between the films, and what they depict, we don't know if there are any other side effects of the serum.  The initial batch did have issues (causing Red Skull's, well, red skull) but that had been worked out by the time Steve Rogers has it administered.  Being put on ice for 70 years or so also means that any decay in his powers could have been halted along with his ageing.

There's a lot of things which could happen and be seen as side effects as *The Avengers* timeline continues, it could be that the effects haven't had time to manifest themselves yet.

Comment: thank you ... @gabe.  for clear clarification .... but I am thinking that  u said **strength is a combination of the serum and his own beliefs and convictions** . Here he injected with -- **Serum**-- but  how serum (camical formula )working this long ... its will not work .. after he  "**Capsicle**" how it re -generating in his body ...

Comment: I'd have to re-watch _The First Avenger_ but unless it has any information, I'd have to speculate at it binding to DNA and it becoming part of who he is from then on.  It will regenerate him and keep him like that as the changes have occurred at a cellular level and below.

Comment: omg... I did't think soo ... technology will grown that much baldly on that time.........  but may be a chance I will look again @gabe..  thank you...

Comment: Well, he can't get drunk. That's one side-effect noted in the movie.

Comment: Excellent answer. In addition, he has military training and is regularly seen training during the movies. This probably contributes to the fact he is unbeatable.

Answer (score 2):

Along with @gabe, Let me show you the storylines..

According to wikipedia:

> The character is usually depicted as the alter ego of Steve Rogers, a frail young man enhanced to the peak of human perfection by an experimental serum to aid the United States government's efforts in World War II. Near the end of the war, he was trapped in ice and survived in suspended animation until he was revived in the present day.

So yes. The government did a superhuman project, and needed a mentally strong person. Steve Rogers and many others was contested, and Steve Rogers had the best courage. He was quite weak though. Theres where the serum takes place. He became strong due to the serum.

Then why doesn't the power decay? I do not clearly know, but I think it is due to the fact that he was trapped in ice.

Comment: yes I am checking it ... but no one giving info about the serum .... and no one concentrate on this .. everyone thinking like he is natural super- hero... like superman.      Thank you. for more info @SIGEGV.  and I did't down voted I upvoted ur answer ....

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR You can probably find some informations in [Captain America Vol.1 #109](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_109).